# Which version of ANSI C standard does Turbo C 3.0 follow?

Tags: c, turbo-c

Which version of ANSI C standard does Turbo C 3.0 follow wholly or partly?

C89 or C90 ?

Comment: It doesn't follow any version of the ANSI C standard, it follows some version of the C++ standard.  C ≠ C++.

Comment: If you meant Turbo C, then it supports C89 as far as I remember.....but most importantly why are you so concerned about that outdated stuff?

Comment: @Prasoon Saurav:  I've got a ton of code around here that's in C89/C90, and some compiler people were awfully slow to implement C99.  A C90 compiler is still very useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turbo C++ 3.0 was released in 1991, which means that in its C compilation it probably supports K&R C and C89 (C90 was essentially identical).  It won't support C95 well, because that version of the standard wasn't available.

Comment: C95 is new to me, but perhaps you meant C99?

Comment: With C95 he probably refers to ISO/IEC 9899:1990 as corrected by ISO/IEC 9899/COR1:1994 and ammended by ISO/IEC 9899/AMD1:1995 and corrected again by ISO/IEC 9899/COR2:1996. Important stuff in AMD1 is wide char functions.

Answer (score 2):

C89 and C90 are essentially the same. C89 refers to ANSI X3.159-1989 "Programming Language C.", while C90 is the ISO version of that (ISO/IEC 9899:1990), with ammendments.